# How to open a second package-explorer window in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

I use Eclipse Neon.3 and work with Working Sets in hierarchial package presentation setting. I use the Java perspective.

And I have two working sets (working-set-new and working-set-old) for two different projects (project-old and project-new).

For a better refactoring of the old project to the new project I want to show both projects in the package exporer. So I want to open the package explorer a second time and put it next to the other package explorer. This might help me a lot to check which classes from the old project I have already moved to the new project (without scolling).

My question is: Can I open a second package explorer? And when yes how?

Or can I do it another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse uses a singleton model for the views, so I don't think you can open a second *Package Explorer* view within the same window.

One option is to open a second window so that *Working-Set-Old* is in the first window and *Working-Set-New* is in the second window.

Open a second window by clicking on *Window* `->` *New Window*

Comment: Hmm, ok. That's a very good alternative and works for me! Thanks a lot! I haven't though about that feature...